# Mi fetch manda un string, pero mi modelo no recibe

Tags: javascript, c#, fetch

empecé un pequeño chat, voy avanzando muy bien pero ahorita me atore con una petición post con fetch, trato de mandar un string pero este lo recibe nulo, ya también lo intente con postman, pero aun asi lo manda nulo.
Ya busque y que yo sepa, esta todo correcto, ayuda por favor.
Así esta mi C#:

```
public IActionResult MensajesChat([FromBody] string idUsuario)
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Este es mi JavaScript:

```
const url = "@Url.Action("MensajesChat","Home")";
const idUser = "Hola mundo"; //En realidad puede ser cualquier cadena
const FetchAPartialView = (idUser) => {
    const valor = JSON.stringify({
        "idUsuario" : idUser
    });
    fetch(url,
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: guardarHeaders(),
            body: valor,
            redirect: "follow"
        }
    ).then(async (resposne) => {
        let respuesta = await resposne.text()
        console.log(respuesta);
    });
};
```

Muchas gracias si me ayudan

Comment: Te sale algún erro en consola?? Agregale un `catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }` al final de tu `.then()` para ver sii captura algun error

Comment: De hecho lo intente, y resulta ser que siempre entra al ```then```, ya que siempre devuelve la vista parcial, solo que el parámetro entra como nulo

Comment: puedes poner tu output en la pregunta para poder verla por favor??

Comment: @AlfaRojo, literalmente lo manda nulo, pero si regresa la vista parcial correctamente, solo que no puedo mandar foto perdon

Comment: Yo ahorita estoy trabajando con llamadas a APIs justamente con fetch, y tengo varios ejemplos que podría pasarte, pero sii el error es que te devuelve null, talvez no es tu fetch, sii no el endpoint(API-url)

Comment: No podría decir que si, ya que si envió un entero y cambio el tipo de dato en el endpoint, este si lo recibirá, pero solo falla cuando es un string, lo máximo que pude arreglarlo es con un object en el endpoint

Comment: Ya trataste de poner tu variable completa de `valor` dentro de tu body??

Comment: Ya y sale igual, no lo detecta, hasta le coloque ```new String(variable) ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puede resolver ese problema creando un modelo (una clase c# por ejemplo UserIdModel) que tenga una prop que sea el string que quieres mandar, después en el método del controlador pones los siguiente `public IActionResult MensajesChat([FromBody] UserIdModel model)` y dentro de la propiedad viene el valor,
La otra solución es la siguiente en js puede hacer esto

```
 const url = "@Url.Action("MensajesChat","Home")";
    const idUser = "Hola mundo"; //En realidad puede ser cualquier cadena
    const FetchAPartialView = (idUser) => {
        const valor = JSON.stringify(idUser);
        fetch(url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: guardarHeaders(),
                body: valor,
                redirect: "follow"
            }
        ).then(async (resposne) => {
            let respuesta = await resposne.text()
            console.log(respuesta);
        });
    };
```

si se fija le hago `stringify` a la variable que tiene el string, con esta variante no tiene que cambiar nada en el controlador
Saludos y espero resuelva

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme de hecho si me sirvió

Comment: Querido compañero, usted es el mejor

Comment: Por nada, me alegro que haya resuelto su problema